# The volume of the voice acquired from the microphone arbitrarily decreases (Android, OpenSLES)

Tags: android, microphone, smartphone, opensl

I am developing an Android smartphone application that inputs a voice from a microphone and outputs the voice with an earphone.

However, when I enter a voice in a microphone, I am bothered by the phenomenon that the volume of the voice acquired from the microphone becomes very small from the middle.
It is a phenomenon that the smartphone automatically lowers the microphone volume (or microphone sensitivity?) If you continue to make loud voices near the microphone.

This phenomenon is occurring in Sony Xperia XZ2 Premium, Xperia XZ2, and it may be a device-dependent problem.

If there is information that can avoid this phenomenon, such as smartphone settings, OpenSLES usage, etc., would you teach me?

- OpenSLES
- Sony Xperia XZ2 Premium, Xperia XZ2
- Android 8.0.0

Thank you.

DSK

Answer (score 0):

I am noticing the same issue, and it also only affects Sony Xperia XA2 Ultra for me.
It seems that whenever the top microphone is being used, the volume is completely inaudible and unusable.